# JQuery .prop() and .attr() setter doesn't work with dialog polyfill

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple dialog tag, which was added by using [GoogleChrome dialog-polyfill.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill)

```
<button id="dialog-show" class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button">Show Dialog</button>

<dialog id="remove-inventory-dialog" class="mdl-dialog">
    <div class="mdl-dialog__title">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button">Ok</button>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</dialog>
```

I tried to add a new data attribute `id` to `<p>` tag by using both jQuery `.prop()` and `.attr()`, but it doesn't work at I expected

```
$('#dialog-show').click(function () {

    $('#remove-inventory-dialog p').text('test value'); // worked
    $('#remove-inventory-dialog p').prop("data-id", 1); // didn't work
    $('#remove-inventory-dialog p').attr("data-id", 1); // didn't work
    $('#remove-inventory-dialog p').data("id", 1); // didn't work

});
```

I google-d alot, but can't find the solution. So how do I solve this problem?

Codepen problematic code : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyZYPK

Comment: Can you show enough code ("[MCVE]") to reproduce your problem? It's worth noting that using `data()` and `attr()` should have worked (albeit `data()` wouldn't show the attribute in the DOM, since it's stored in a data object rather than assigned as an attribute to the element).

Comment: I have added problematic code into Codepen.io, please take a look at main question for link

Comment: It actually works... in Chrome. Are you still having the problem?

Comment: @rma, weird, actually I'm using Google Chrome Version 48.0.2564.82 (64-bit), didn't think it's caused by browser, but when I try it with Firefox it's working perfectly, so I can conclude the cause and answer now

Comment: I'm using Chrome 48.0.2564.103 (32bit)... shame on Chrome 64bit? lol. But still love chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David Thomas is correct, place this after your JQuery code and you will see that you have set the data-id value.

JQuery(http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/WraPPw):

```
var data = '#remove-inventory-dialog p';

//alert the data value you set (returns 1)
alert($(data).data("id"));
```

or you could use console log(right click on page and click inspect element then click on the console tab):

```
//display to the console the data value you set (returns 1)
console.log($(data).data("id"));
```

You can see what David Thomas is talking about by console logging the data object:

```
var data = '#remove-inventory-dialog p';

console.log($(data).data());
```

Image of console log results:
[image]

If you click on the Object in the console you will see that it has an id property with a value of 1.

Data Object Properties:
[image]

Comment: This is actually caused by Google Chrome Version 48.0.2564.82 (64-bit). By using a Firefox browser, my code working perfectly without any problem.

Comment: thanks for your great answer in trying to help me @Larry Lane :)